# createinstance Recursively using Reflection

Tags: c#, recursion, reflection

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length >= 1 && args[0] == "ContainerTest")
        {
            string fullname = "xxx.xxx.AddOptionalComponentDialog";

            //string formType = "PropertySheet";
            string formType = "CustomDialog";
            Type type = null;
            try
            {
                Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\temp\45e2f339-aa63-4525-b722-8e6541873f3b\bin\xxx.dll");
                type = asm.GetType(fullname, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string msg = e.Message;
            }


            Object ret = CreateForm(formType, type, ActivationMode.CodeExecutionPriorityMixed);
            if (ret is Form)
            {
                Form tForm = (Form)ret;

                Application.Run(tForm);
            }
            else
            {

            }
            return;
        }
```

}
static Object CreateForm(string formType, Type controlType, ActivationMode mode)
        {
            Form ret = null;

```
    retry:
        switch (formType)
        {
            case "PropertySheet":

            case "CustomDialog":
                ret = (Form)InstanceCreator.CreateInstance(controlType, true);
                if (ret != null)
                {
                    ret.AccessibleName = controlType.FullName;
                }
                break;

            default:
                {
                    if (controlType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SmsPageControl)))
                    {
                        formType = "PropertySheet";
                        goto retry;
                    }
                    if (controlType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form)))
                    {
                        formType = "CustomDialog";
                        goto retry;
                    }
                    if (controlType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SmsWizardPage)))
                        //||                            controlType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SmsPropertyPage)))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("There is no need to check this control");
                    }
                    UserControl control = (UserControl)CreateInstanceOfType(controlType, mode);
                    UserControlHolder holder = new UserControlHolder();
                    holder.HostUserControl(control);
                    ret = holder;
                }
                break;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

public static object CreateInstance(Type type, bool genParam)
        {
            var constructors = type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

```
        if (!genParam || constructors.Any(x => !x.GetParameters().Any()))
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new object[] { }, null);
        }

        foreach (var constructor in constructors.Where(x => x.GetParameters().Any()))
        {
            return constructor.Invoke(constructor.GetParameters().Select(x => CreateInstance(x.ParameterType, true)).ToArray());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are trying to do?  You want to reflectively create an instance of a class; and if that class has properties, also reflectively instantiate each property to an instance of its type?

Comment: i tried your code, it will fail with "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Comment: yeah, I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  I'm taking another look now

Answer (score 1):

Updating code, try this:  will recursively create an object with or without parameterless constructors.  Should also handle private and internal types.

```
    public static object CreateInstance(Type type, bool genParam)
    {
        var constructors = type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (!genParam || constructors.Any(x => !x.GetParameters().Any()))
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new object[] { }, null);
        }

        foreach (var constructor in constructors)
        {
            try
            {
                return constructor.Invoke(constructor.GetParameters().Select(x => CreateInstance(x.ParameterType, true)).ToArray());
            }
            catch{}
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The .Any is a LINQ extension methods: [.Any()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

constructors.Any(x => !x.GetParameters().Any()) checks if there are any constructors which do not have any parameters (i.e. parameterless constructors).  If there is a parameterless ctor, then Activator.CreateInstance can be used to create the type.

If no parameterless constructor was found then each remaining constructor is tried to see if an instance of the class can be created.  At this point the CreateInstance method is recursively called to create the parameters needed by the constructor.

Comment: Thanks your reply, my question is when Type contain one parameterless constructor and parameter constructer, and some parameter is internal or private, my code cannot handle it, i have no idea how to recursive them

Comment: constructors.Any and Where ?

Comment: I'll update the answer with explanation of those methods

Comment: I simplified the code a little and removed the .Where

Comment: yes i add system.linq, it returns an object, but when use the object to create form     {Form tForm=(Form)instance; Application.Run(tForm);}
 it fails with bject reference not set to an instance of an object. which means some paramter which needed doesn't set value

Comment: can you post the code you are calling the method with?

Comment: sure, but how can i pop my code, the comment has text limited Object instance= CreateForm(formType, type, ActivationMode.CodeExecutionPriorityMixed);
                if (instance is Form)
                {
                    Form tForm = (Form)instance;

                    Application.Run(tForm);
                }
                else
                {
                    
                }
                return;

Comment: You can edit the original question to show the code of the object which you are trying to reflectively create

Comment: i just edit my code , on main() which has createform(), createform will call createinstance()

Comment: oh, bty, it fail at onload（） event AddOptionalComponentDialog.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl